# Subtract Using GravityWP Count Plugin

Tags: plugins, php, shortcode

I'm currently using [GravityWP Count plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/gravitywp-count/) for entry totals on number fields. To this end I also needed to subtract totals via a shortcode. I reached out to the plugin author who kindly responded but I'm sure has other things to do.

```
if (class_exists("GFForms")) {

 function gravitywp_count_func( $atts, $content = null ) {
    extract( shortcode_atts( array(
    'formid' => '0',
    'formstatus' => 'active',
    'number_field' => false,
    'filter_mode' => 'all',
    'add_number' => '0',
    'sub_number' => '0',
    'filter_field' => false,
    'filter_operator' => 'is',
    'filter_value' => false,
    'filter_field2' => false,
    'filter_operator2' => 'is',
    'filter_value2' => false,
    'filter_field3' => false,
    'filter_operator3' => 'is',
    'filter_value3' => false,
    'filter_field4' => false,
    'filter_operator4' => 'is',
    'filter_value4' => false,
    'filter_field5' => false,
    'filter_operator5' => 'is',
    'filter_value5' => false,
    'decimals' => '2',
    'dec_point' => '.',
    'thousands_sep' => ',',
    'created_by' => '',
    'page_size' => '500',
    'is_starred' => '',
    'is_read' => '',
    'multiply' => '1',
    'start_date' => false,
    'end_date' => false
    ), $atts ) );

if ( $formstatus != 'all' ) {
$search_criteria['status'] = $formstatus;
}

$search_criteria['field_filters']['mode'] = $filter_mode;

if ( !empty( $filter_field ) ) {
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => $filter_field, 'operator' => $filter_operator, 'value' => $filter_value);
}
if ( !empty( $filter_field2 ) ) {
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => $filter_field2, 'operator' => $filter_operator2, 'value' => $filter_value2);
} 
if ( !empty( $filter_field3 ) ) {
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => $filter_field3, 'operator' => $filter_operator3, 'value' => $filter_value3);
} 
if ( !empty( $filter_field4 ) ) {
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => $filter_field4, 'operator' => $filter_operator4, 'value' => $filter_value4);
} 
if ( !empty( $filter_field5 ) ) {
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => $filter_field5, 'operator' => $filter_operator5, 'value' => $filter_value5);
} 
if ( !empty( $created_by ) ) {
if ($created_by == "current") {
    $user_ID = get_current_user_id();
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => 'created_by', 'value' => $user_ID);
} else {
    $search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => 'created_by', 'value' => $created_by);
}
} 

if ( $is_starred == "yes" ) {
$search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => 'is_starred', 'value' => true);
}   
if ( $is_starred == "no" ) {
$search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => 'is_starred', 'value' => false);
}   

if ( $is_read == "yes" ) {
$search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => 'is_read', 'value' => true);
} 
if ( $is_read == "no" ) {
$search_criteria['field_filters'][] = array('key' => 'is_read', 'value' => false);
} 

if ( !empty( $start_date ) ) {
$date_start = date_create( $start_date );
if ($date_start) {
$search_criteria['start_date'] = $date_start->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ); } 
else {
    echo "Oops... your start_date format is not correct: " . $start_date . " 
(must be Month/Day/Year)<br>Change the start_date in your gravitywp_count 
shortcode.<br>";
}
}

if ( !empty( $end_date ) ) {
$date_end = date_create( $end_date );
if ($date_end) {
$search_criteria['end_date'] = $date_end->format( 'Y-m-d H:i:s' ); } else {
    echo "Oops... your send_date format is not correct: " . $end_date . " 
 (must be Month/Day/Year)<br>Change the start_date in your gravitywp_count 
 shortcode.<br>";
 }
 } 

$sorting = null;
$paging = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => $page_size );
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries($formid, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging);
$countentries = GFAPI::count_entries( $formid, $search_criteria );
$countentries_add = $add_number + $countentries;
if ( !empty( $number_field ) ) {
    $gwp_count = $add_number;
        for ($row = 0; $row < $countentries ; $row++) {
            $gwp_count += $entries[$row][$number_field];}
            return number_format($gwp_count * $multiply, $decimals, 
$dec_point, $thousands_sep);
} else {
    return number_format($countentries_add * $multiply, "0", ".", 
 $thousands_sep);
    }


$sorting = null;
$paging = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => $page_size );
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries($formid, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging);
$countentries = GFAPI::count_entries( $formid, $search_criteria );
$countentries_sub = $sub_number - $countentries;
if ( !empty( $number_field ) ) {
    $gwp_count = $sub_number;
        for ($row = 0; $row < $countentries ; $row--) {
            $gwp_count -= $entries[$row][$number_field];}
            return number_format($gwp_count * $multiply, $decimals, 
$dec_point, $thousands_sep);
} else {
    return number_format($countentries_sub * $multiply, "0", ".", 
$thousands_sep);
    }
}



add_shortcode( 'gravitywp_count', 'gravitywp_count_func' );

}
```

**Shortcode:**

```
Budget Total: $[gravitywp_count formid="8" sub_number="250000" 
number_field="37" filter_field="29" filter_value="Budget"  thousands_sep=","]
```

But it doesn't return a value.

**add_number shortcode:**

```
Budget Total: $[gravitywp_count formid="8" add_number="-250000" 
number_field="37" filter_field="29" filter_value="Budget" thousands_sep=","]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Note:** the plugin lets you use the add_number shortcode with a - (minus) sign in front of the subtracting number but that returns a negative number. The shortcode above returns -245,000 instead of 245,000.

Comment: have you added it as a separate function? have you added it as a shortcode? or if you are using the same function, have you taken care of the new attribute sub_number?

Comment: @inarilo yes, I added a function: 'sub_number' => '0', and added it as a shortcode: sub_number. I also updated my question.

Comment: do you have an if condition separating which block of code to use? passing -250000 probably returns -245000 because it's adding 5000 to -250000.

Comment: @inarilo I'm not sure what you mean. Do you have an example?

Comment: it'll be easier if you post the full code for gravitywp_count_func

Comment: @inarilo Added full code.

Comment: I don;t think the sub_number code is ever reached, the bit before that though ought to return a value? Your loop is also wrong, you are reducing the row number, that will result in an infinite loop. But first you need an if condition to determine which code to run, the add_number bit or the sub_number bit.

Comment: you can simplify this though, if you know that adding will always use a +ve value for add_number and subtracting a -ve one.

Comment: @inarilo I updated row++, how would I simplify it? Also thank you so much for the guidance!

Comment: you're welcome :) see my answer, I have given two options, let me know if it works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `$add_number` if `$sub_number` is `0`, else use `$sub_number`:

```
$sorting = null;
$paging = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => $page_size );
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries($formid, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging);
$countentries = GFAPI::count_entries( $formid, $search_criteria );

if(!$sub_number) {
    $countentries_add = $add_number + $countentries;
    if ( !empty( $number_field ) ) {
        $gwp_count = $add_number;
            for ($row = 0; $row < $countentries ; $row++) {
                $gwp_count += $entries[$row][$number_field];}
                return number_format($gwp_count * $multiply, $decimals, 
    $dec_point, $thousands_sep);
    } else {
        return number_format($countentries_add * $multiply, "0", ".", 
     $thousands_sep);
        }
} else {
    $countentries_sub = $sub_number - $countentries;
    if ( !empty( $number_field ) ) {
        $gwp_count = $sub_number;
            for ($row = 0; $row < $countentries ; $row++) {
                $gwp_count -= $entries[$row][$number_field];}
                return number_format($gwp_count * $multiply, $decimals, 
    $dec_point, $thousands_sep);
    } else {
        return number_format($countentries_sub * $multiply, "0", ".", 
$thousands_sep);
        }
}
```

The loop will still increase the row count, you can't count row numbers down from 0.

Or if you know `$add_number` is negative only if you want to subtract, you can use:

```
$sorting = null;
$paging = array( 'offset' => 0, 'page_size' => $page_size );
$entries = GFAPI::get_entries($formid, $search_criteria, $sorting, $paging);
$countentries = GFAPI::count_entries( $formid, $search_criteria );
$countentries_add = $add_number + $countentries;
if ( !empty( $number_field ) ) {
    $gwp_count = $add_number;
        for ($row = 0; $row < $countentries ; $row++) {
            $gwp_count += $entries[$row][$number_field];}
            if($add_number < 0) $gwp_count *= -1;
            return number_format($gwp_count * $multiply, $decimals, 
$dec_point, $thousands_sep);
} else {
    if($add_number < 0) $countentries_add *= -1;
    return number_format($countentries_add * $multiply, "0", ".", 
 $thousands_sep);
        }
```

Comment: Thank you so much @inarilo works perfectly! And now I see what you were referring to. Thanks again for the help and knowledge.

Comment: you're welcome :) just out of curiosity, which version did you use?

Comment: I used: Use $add_number if $sub_number is 0, else use $sub_number: